# Draw Sphere on TImage control of Delphi

Tags: delphi, 3d, geometry

I want to draw sphere like this:
[image]

Below code is generates Circle's Vertices and Drawing a Circle on TIMAGE BUT i want it for SPHERE:

```
for i := 0 to 360 do begin 
   //Find value of X and Y 
   pntCordXY.X := Radius * Cos(DegToRad(i)); 
   pntCordXY.Y := Radius * Sin(DegToRad(i)); 
   if i = 0 then 
      image1.Canvas.MoveTo(Round(pntCordXY.X), Round(pntCordXY.Y)) 
   else 
      image1.Canvas.LineTo(Round(pntCordXY.X), Round(pntCordXY.Y)); 
end;
```

Comment: a complete example with source can be found on http://spheredelphi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: FYI I would draw circles with TCanvas.Ellipse http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.Ellipse

Comment: @SirRufo for 3D he will need to drawe "circles" on his own

Comment: Can you describe the projection that you are looking for?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, i'm looking for XYZ at Zero projection means without any rotated points.

Comment: I've no idea what that means. Do you want an isometric projection?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ya, A two-dimensional perspective projection of a sphere.

Comment: Just to clarify: 'like this' means that you want to draw the parameter curves of the standard parameterisation (x, y, z) = (r sin θ cos φ, r sin θ sin φ, r cos θ), that is, the image of a rectangular grid in the parameter plane (well, the rectangle [0, π]×[0, 2π)).

Comment: Er, perspective and isometric are different. Which is it?

Comment: @bummi, i can't download file from Sourceforge due to technical reason.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, any kind of projection method i accept.

Comment: FWIW, I do all my 3D rendering using OpenGL: http://english.rejbrand.se/algosim/visualisation.asp That way you get the projection part for free, and you get very high performance. But I have also tried doing things manually, using only the GDI: http://privat.rejbrand.se/d3grphing.exe

Comment: If you have further needs for 3D graphics, check out [GLScene](http://glscene.sourceforge.net/wikka/HomePage) -library.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This turned out to be a fun exercise; nice question!

At first, you ask specifically for drawing such a sphere on a `TImage`, but that component is supposed to be used for showing graphics. Sure, it has a canvas on which can be drawn, but hereunder I use a `TPaintBox` which is the preferred component for own painting. Because, you will have to paint this yourself. Entirely.

#### Ingredients needed:

- Some math for calculating the 3D points on a sphere, for rotating the globe around multiple axes, and maybe for converting the 3D points to the 2D screen coordinate system. The basics are:

  ```
  type
    TPoint3D = record
      X: Double;
      Y: Double;
      Z: Double;
    end;

  function Sphere(Phi, Lambda: Double): TPoint3D;
  begin
    Result.X := Cos(Phi) * Sin(Lambda);
    Result.Y := Sin(Phi);
    Result.Z := Cos(Phi) * Cos(Lambda);
  end;

  function RotateAroundX(const P: TPoint3D; Alfa: Double): TPoint3D;
  begin
    Result.X := P.X;
    Result.Y := P.Y * Cos(Alfa) + P.Z * Sin(Alfa);
    Result.Z := P.Y * -Sin(Alfa) + P.Z * Cos(Alfa);
  end;

  function RotateAroundY(const P: TPoint3D; Beta: Double): TPoint3D;
  begin
    Result.X := P.X * Cos(Beta) + P.Z * Sin(Beta);
    Result.Y := P.Y;
    Result.Z := P.X * -Sin(Beta) + P.Z * Cos(Beta);
  end;
  ```
- Some globe-variables to work with:

  ```
  var
    Alfa: Integer;   //Rotation around X axis
    Beta: Integer;   //Rotation around Y axis
    C: TPoint;       //Center
    R: Integer;      //Radius
    Phi: Integer;    //Angle relative to XY plane
    Lambda: Integer; //Angle around Z axis (from pole to pole)
    P: TPoint3D;     //2D projection of a 3D point on the sphere's surface
  ```
- Code to calculate all points of the latitude circles:

  ```
  for Phi := -8 to 8 do
    for Lambda := 0 to 360 do
    begin
      P := Sphere(DegToRad(Phi * 10), DegToRad(Lambda));
      P := RotateAroundX(P, Alfa);
      P := RotateAroundY(P, Beta);
    end;
  ```
- Code to calculate all points of the longitude meridians:

  ```
  for Lambda := 0 to 17 do
    for Phi := 0 to 360 do
    begin
      P := Sphere(DegToRad(Phi), DegToRad(Lambda * 10));
      P := RotateAroundX(P, Alfa);
      P := RotateAroundY(P, Beta);
    end;
  ```

  These points can be used to draw lines or curves on the paint box. The Z value of these points are not used for drawing, but they are helpful to decide whether the point lies on the back or front side of the globe.
- Logic and aids. Before all points, lines or curves in front of the globe can be drawn, the ones in the back of globe have to be drawn first, in order to preserve *depth*.
- A drawing framework or drawing library. Delphi is by default equipped with standard Windows GDI, available via the `Canvas` property of the paint box. Another possibility is GDI+ which is more advanced and can be more efficient. Especially considering anti-aliassing. These are the two frameworks I worked with, but there are also others. For example: OpenGL, which converts 3D objects to 2D automatically and is capable of adding 3D surfaces, lights, materials, shaders, and many more features.
- A testing application, which is added at the bottom of this question.
- A double buffering technique to get the paint work flicker-free. I chose a separate bitmap object on which everything is drawn, prior to painting that bitmap on the paint box. The demo program also demonstrates the performance without it (routine: `GDIMultipleColorsDirect`).

#### Setup:

Drop a paint box on your form, and set its `Align` property to `alClient`, add a timer component for simulation, add form event handlers for `OnCreate`, `OnDestroy`, `OnKeyPress`, and `OnResize`, and add an event handler for `PaintBox1.OnPaint`.

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 497
  Top = 394
  Width = 450
  Height = 450
  Caption = 'Sphere'
  Color = clWhite
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnDestroy = FormDestroy
  OnKeyPress = FormKeyPress
  OnResize = FormResize
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object PaintBox1: TPaintBox
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 434
    Height = 414
    Align = alClient
    OnPaint = PaintBox1Paint
  end
  object Timer1: TTimer
    Interval = 25
    OnTimer = Timer1Timer
    Left = 7
    Top = 7
  end
end
```

#### First attempt:

With default GDI, I draw lines from every point to every next point. To add a feeling of depth (perspective), I gave the lines in front a greater width. Also, I gradually let the colors of the lines overflow from dark to light (routine: `GDIMultipleColors`).

[image: Sphere 1]

#### Second attempt:

Nice, but all pixels are so hard! Let's try doing some anti-aliassing ourselfs... ;) Furthermore, I reduced the color count to two: dark in front, light in the back. This in order to get rid of all separate line segments: now every circle and meridian is devided into two polylines. I used a third color in between for the anti-aliassing effect (routine: `GDIThreeColors`).

[image: Sphere 2]

#### GDI+ to the rescue:

This anti-aliassing isn't most charming. To get really smooth paint work, let's convert the code to GDI+ style. For Delphi 2009 and up, the library is available [from here](http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/index.shtml). For older Delphi versions, the library is available [from here](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=7).

In GDI+, drawing works a bit differently. Create a `TGPGraphics` object and attach it to a device context with its constructor. Subsequently, drawing operations on the object are translated by the API and will be output to the destination context, the bitmap in this case (routine: `GDIPlusDualLinewidths`).

[image: Sphere 3]

#### Can it even better?

Well, that's quite someting already. But this globe is made up out of polylines with just two different line widths. Let's add some in between. The count of segments in each circle or meridian is controlled by the `Precision` constant (routine: `GDIPlusMultipleLinewidths`).

[image]

#### Sample application:

Press a key to cycle through the above mentioned routines.

```
unit Globe;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, ExtCtrls, Math,
  GDIPAPI, GDIPOBJ;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PaintBox1: TPaintBox;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    procedure PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FBmp: TBitmap;
    FPen: TGPPen;
    procedure GDIMultipleColorsDirect;
    procedure GDIMultipleColors;
    procedure GDIThreeColors;
    procedure GDIPlusDualLinewidths;
    procedure GDIPlusMultipleLinewidths;
  public
    A: Integer; //Alfa, rotation round X axis
    B: Integer; //Beta, rotation round Y axis
    C: TPoint;  //Center
    R: Integer; //Radius
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

const
  LineColorFore = $00552B00;
  LineColorMiddle = $00AA957F;
  LineColorBack = $00FFDFBF;
  BackColor = clWhite;
  LineWidthFore = 4.5;
  LineWidthBack = 1.5;
  Precision = 10; //Should be even!

type
  TCycle = 0..Precision - 1;

  TPoint3D = record
    X: Double;
    Y: Double;
    Z: Double;
  end;

function Sphere(Phi, Lambda: Double): TPoint3D;
begin
  Result.X := Cos(Phi) * Sin(Lambda);
  Result.Y := Sin(Phi);
  Result.Z := Cos(Phi) * Cos(Lambda);
end;

function RotateAroundX(const P: TPoint3D; Alfa: Double): TPoint3D;
begin
  Result.X := P.X;
  Result.Y := P.Y * Cos(Alfa) + P.Z * Sin(Alfa);
  Result.Z := P.Y * -Sin(Alfa) + P.Z * Cos(Alfa);
end;

function RotateAroundY(const P: TPoint3D; Beta: Double): TPoint3D;
begin
  Result.X := P.X * Cos(Beta) + P.Z * Sin(Beta);
  Result.Y := P.Y;
  Result.Z := P.X * -Sin(Beta) + P.Z * Cos(Beta);
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Brush.Style := bsClear; //This is múch cheaper then DoubleBuffered := True
  FBmp := TBitmap.Create;
  FPen := TGPPen.Create(ColorRefToARGB(ColorToRGB(clBlack)));
  A := 35;
  B := 25;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FPen.Free;
  FBmp.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  C.X := PaintBox1.ClientWidth div 2;
  C.Y := PaintBox1.ClientHeight div 2;
  R := Min(C.X, C.Y) - 10;
  FBmp.Width := PaintBox1.ClientWidth;
  FBmp.Height := PaintBox1.ClientHeight;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  A := A + 2;
  B := B + 1;
  PaintBox1.Invalidate;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  Tag := Tag + 1;
  PaintBox1.Invalidate;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case Tag mod 5 of
    0: GDIMultipleColorsDirect;
    1: GDIMultipleColors;
    2: GDIThreeColors;
    3: GDIPlusDualLinewidths;
    4: GDIPlusMultipleLinewidths;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.GDIPlusMultipleLinewidths;
var
  Lines: array of TPointFDynArray;
  PointCount: Integer;
  LineCount: Integer;
  Drawing: TGPGraphics;
  Alfa: Double;
  Beta: Double;
  Cycle: TCycle;
  Phi: Integer;
  Lambda: Integer;
  P: TPoint3D;
  Filter: TCycle;
  PrevFilter: TCycle;
  I: Integer;

  procedure ResetLines;
  begin
    SetLength(Lines, 0);
    LineCount := 0;
    PointCount := 0;
  end;

  procedure FinishLastLine;
  begin
    if PointCount < 2 then
      Dec(LineCount)
    else
      SetLength(Lines[LineCount - 1], PointCount);
  end;

  procedure NewLine;
  begin
    if LineCount > 0 then
      FinishLastLine;
    SetLength(Lines, LineCount + 1);
    SetLength(Lines[LineCount], 361);
    Inc(LineCount);
    PointCount := 0;
  end;

  procedure AddPoint(X, Y: Single);
  begin
    Lines[LineCount - 1][PointCount] := MakePoint(X, Y);
    Inc(PointCount);
  end;

  function CycleFromZ(Z: Single): TCycle;
  begin
    Result := Round((Z + 1) / 2 * High(TCycle));
  end;

  function CycleToLineWidth(ACycle: TCycle): Single;
  begin
    Result := LineWidthBack +
      (LineWidthFore - LineWidthBack) * (ACycle / High(TCycle));
  end;

  function CycleToLineColor(ACycle: TCycle): TGPColor;
  begin
    if ACycle <= (High(TCycle) div 2) then
      Result := ColorRefToARGB(ColorToRGB(LineColorBack))
    else
      Result := ColorRefToARGB(ColorToRGB(LineColorFore));
  end;

begin
  Drawing := TGPGraphics.Create(FBmp.Canvas.Handle);
  try
    Drawing.Clear(ColorRefToARGB(ColorToRGB(clWhite)));
    Drawing.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias);
    Alfa := DegToRad(A);
    Beta := DegToRad(B);
    for Cycle := Low(TCycle) to High(TCycle) do
    begin
      ResetLines;
      //Latitude
      for Phi := -8 to 8 do
      begin
        NewLine;
        PrevFilter := 0;
        for Lambda := 0 to 360 do
        begin
          P := Sphere(DegToRad(Phi * 10), DegToRad(Lambda));
          P := RotateAroundX(P, Alfa);
          P := RotateAroundY(P, Beta);
          Filter := CycleFromZ(P.Z);
          if Filter <> PrevFilter then
          begin
            AddPoint(C.X + P.X * R, C.Y + P.Y * R);
            NewLine;
          end;
          if Filter = Cycle then
            AddPoint(C.X + P.X * R, C.Y + P.Y * R);
          PrevFilter := Filter;
        end;
      end;
      //Longitude
      for Lambda := 0 to 17 do
      begin
        NewLine;
        PrevFilter := 0;
        for Phi := 0 to 360 do
        begin
          P := Sphere(DegToRad(Phi), DegToRad(Lambda * 10));
          P := RotateAroundX(P, Alfa);
          P := RotateAroundY(P, Beta);
          Filter := CycleFromZ(P.Z);
          if Filter <> PrevFilter then
          begin
            AddPoint(C.X + P.X * R, C.Y + P.Y * R);
            NewLine;
          end;
          if Filter = Cycle then
            AddPoint(C.X + P.X * R, C.Y + P.Y * R);
          PrevFilter := Filter;
        end;
      end;
      FinishLastLine;
      FPen.SetColor(CycleToLineColor(Cycle));
      FPen.SetWidth(CycleToLineWidth(Cycle));
      for I := 0 to LineCount - 1 do
        Drawing.DrawLines(FPen, PGPPointF(@(Lines[I][0])), Length(Lines[I]));
      if Cycle = (High(TCycle) div 2 + 1) then
        Drawing.DrawEllipse(FPen, C.X - R, C.Y - R, 2 * R, 2 * R);
    end;
  finally
    Drawing.Free;
  end;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, FBmp);
end;

procedure TForm1.GDIPlusDualLinewidths;
const
  LineColors: array[Boolean] of TColor = (LineColorFore, LineColorBack);
  LineWidths: array[Boolean] of Single = (LineWidthFore, LineWidthBack);
  BackColor = clWhite;
var
  Lines: array of TPointFDynArray;
  PointCount: Integer;
  LineCount: Integer;
  Drawing: TGPGraphics;
  Alfa: Double;
  Beta: Double;
  Phi: Integer;
  Lambda: Integer;
  BackSide: Boolean;
  P: TPoint3D;
  PrevZ: Double;
  I: Integer;

  procedure ResetLines;
  begin
    SetLength(Lines, 0);
    LineCount := 0;
    PointCount := 0;
  end;

  procedure FinishLastLine;
  begin
    if PointCount < 2 then
      Dec(LineCount)
    else
      SetLength(Lines[LineCount - 1], PointCount);
  end;

  procedure NewLine;
  begin
    if LineCount > 0 then
      FinishLastLine;
    SetLength(Lines, LineCount + 1);
    SetLength(Lines[LineCount], 361);
    Inc(LineCount);
    PointCount := 0;
  end;

  procedure AddPoint(X, Y: Single);
  begin
    Lines[LineCount - 1][PointCount] := MakePoint(X, Y);
    Inc(PointCount);
  end;

begin
  Drawing := TGPGraphics.Create(FBmp.Canvas.Handle);
  try
    Drawing.Clear(ColorRefToARGB(ColorToRGB(clWhite)));
    Drawing.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias);
    Alfa := DegToRad(A);
    Beta := DegToRad(B);
    for BackSide := True downto False do
    begin
      ResetLines;
      //Latitude
      for Phi := -8 to 8 do
      begin
        NewLine;
        PrevZ := 0;
        for Lambda := 0 to 360 do
        begin
          P := Sphere(DegToRad(Phi * 10), DegToRad(Lambda));
          P := RotateAroundX(P, Alfa);
          P := RotateAroundY(P, Beta);
          if Sign(P.Z) <> Sign(PrevZ) then
            NewLine;
          if (BackSide and (P.Z < 0)) or (not BackSide and (P.Z >= 0)) then
            AddPoint(C.X + P.X * R, C.Y + P.Y * R);
          PrevZ := P.Z;
        end;
      end;
      //Longitude
      for Lambda := 0 to 17 do
      begin
        NewLine;
        PrevZ := 0;
        for Phi := 0 to 360 do
        begin
          P := Sphere(DegToRad(Phi), DegToRad(Lambda * 10));
          P := RotateAroundX(P, Alfa);
          P := RotateAroundY(P, Beta);
          if Sign(P.Z) <> Sign(PrevZ) then
            NewLine;
          if (BackSide and (P.Z < 0)) or (not BackSide and (P.Z >= 0)) then
            AddPoint(C.X + P.X * R, C.Y + P.Y * R);
          PrevZ := P.Z;
        end;
      end;
      FinishLastLine;
      FPen.SetColor(ColorRefToARGB(ColorToRGB(LineColors[BackSide])));
      FPen.SetWidth(LineWidths[BackSide]);
      for I := 0 to LineCount - 1 do
        Drawing.DrawLines(FPen, PGPPointF(@(Lines[I][0])), Length(Lines[I]));
    end;
    Drawing.DrawEllipse(FPen, C.X - R, C.Y - R, 2 * R, 2 * R);
  finally
    Drawing.Free;
  end;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, FBmp);
end;

procedure TForm1.GDIThreeColors;
const
  LineColors: array[TValueSign] of TColor = (LineColorBack, LineColorMiddle,
    LineColorFore);
  LineWidths: array[TValueSign] of Integer = (2, 4, 2);
var
  Lines: array of array of TPoint;
  PointCount: Integer;
  LineCount: Integer;
  Alfa: Double;
  Beta: Double;
  Phi: Integer;
  Lambda: Integer;
  BackSide: Boolean;
  P: TPoint3D;
  PrevZ: Double;
  I: TValueSign;
  J: Integer;

  procedure ResetLines;
  begin
    SetLength(Lines, 0);
    LineCount := 0;
    PointCount := 0;
  end;

  procedure FinishLastLine;
  begin
    if PointCount < 2 then
      Dec(LineCount)
    else
      SetLength(Lines[LineCount - 1], PointCount);
  end;

  procedure NewLine;
  begin
    if LineCount > 0 then
      FinishLastLine;
    SetLength(Lines, LineCount + 1);
    SetLength(Lines[LineCount], 361);
    Inc(LineCount);
    PointCount := 0;
  end;

  procedure AddPoint(APoint: TPoint); overload;
  var
    Last: TPoint;
  begin
    if PointCount > 0 then
    begin
      Last := Lines[LineCount - 1][PointCount - 1];
      if (APoint.X = Last.X) and (APoint.Y = Last.Y) then
        Exit;
    end;
    Lines[LineCount - 1][PointCount] := APoint;
    Inc(PointCount);
  end;

  procedure AddPoint(X, Y: Integer); overload;
  begin
    AddPoint(Point(X, Y));
  end;

begin
  FBmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := BackColor;
  FBmp.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, FBmp.Width, FBmp.Height));
  Alfa := DegToRad(A);
  Beta := DegToRad(B);
  for BackSide := True downto False do
  begin
    ResetLines;
    //Latitude
    for Phi := -8 to 8 do
    begin
      NewLine;
      PrevZ := 0;
      for Lambda := 0 to 360 do
      begin
        P := Sphere(DegToRad(Phi * 10), DegToRad(Lambda));
        P := RotateAroundX(P, Alfa);
        P := RotateAroundY(P, Beta);
        if Sign(P.Z) <> Sign(PrevZ) then
          NewLine;
        if (BackSide and (P.Z < 0)) or (not BackSide and (P.Z >= 0)) then
          AddPoint(Round(C.X + P.X * R), Round(C.Y + P.Y * R));
        PrevZ := P.Z;
      end;
    end;
    //Longitude
    for Lambda := 0 to 17 do
    begin
      NewLine;
      PrevZ := 0;
      for Phi := 0 to 360 do
      begin
        P := Sphere(DegToRad(Phi), DegToRad(Lambda * 10));
        P := RotateAroundX(P, Alfa);
        P := RotateAroundY(P, Beta);
        if Sign(P.Z) <> Sign(PrevZ) then
          NewLine;
        if (BackSide and (P.Z < 0)) or (not BackSide and (P.Z >= 0)) then
          AddPoint(Round(C.X + P.X * R), Round(C.Y + P.Y * R));
        PrevZ := P.Z;
      end;
    end;
    FinishLastLine;
    if BackSide then
    begin
      FBmp.Canvas.Pen.Color := LineColors[-1];
      FBmp.Canvas.Pen.Width := LineWidths[-1];
      for J := 0 to LineCount - 1 do
        FBmp.Canvas.Polyline(Lines[J]);
    end
    else
      for I := 0 to 1 do
      begin
        FBmp.Canvas.Pen.Color := LineColors[I];
        FBmp.Canvas.Pen.Width := LineWidths[I];
        for J := 0 to LineCount - 1 do
          FBmp.Canvas.Polyline(Lines[J])
      end
  end;
  FBmp.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  FBmp.Canvas.Ellipse(C.X - R, C.Y - R, C.X + R, C.Y + R);
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, FBmp);
end;

procedure TForm1.GDIMultipleColors;
var
  Alfa: Double;
  Beta: Double;
  Phi: Integer;
  Lambda: Integer;
  P: TPoint3D;
  Backside: Boolean;

  function ColorFromZ(Z: Single): TColorRef;
  var
    R: Integer;
    G: Integer;
    B: Integer;
  begin
    Z := (Z + 1) / 2;
    R := GetRValue(LineColorFore) - GetRValue(LineColorBack);
    R := GetRValue(LineColorBack) + Round(Z * R);
    G := GetGValue(LineColorFore) - GetGValue(LineColorBack);
    G := GetGValue(LineColorBack) + Round(Z * G);
    B := GetBValue(LineColorFore) - GetBValue(LineColorBack);
    B := GetBValue(LineColorBack) + Round(Z * B);
    Result := RGB(R, G, B);
  end;

begin
  FBmp.Canvas.Pen.Width := 2;
  FBmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := BackColor;
  FBmp.Canvas.FillRect(PaintBox1.ClientRect);
  Alfa := DegToRad(A);
  Beta := DegToRad(B);
  for Backside := True downto False do
  begin
    if not BackSide then
      FBmp.Canvas.Pen.Width := 3;
    //Latitude
    for Phi := -8 to 8 do
      for Lambda := 0 to 360 do
      begin
        P := Sphere(DegToRad(Phi * 10), DegToRad(Lambda));
        P := RotateAroundX(P, Alfa);
        P := RotateAroundY(P, Beta);
        if (Lambda = 0) or (Backside and (P.Z >= 0)) or
          (not Backside and (P.Z < 0)) then
            FBmp.Canvas.MoveTo(C.X + Round(P.X * R), C.Y + Round(P.Y * R))
        else
        begin
          FBmp.Canvas.Pen.Color := ColorFromZ(P.Z);
          FBmp.Canvas.LineTo(C.X + Round(P.X * R), C.Y + Round(P.Y * R));
        end;
      end;
    //Longitude
    for Lambda := 0 to 17 do
      for Phi := 0 to 360 do
      begin
        P := Sphere(DegToRad(Phi), DegToRad(Lambda * 10));
        P := RotateAroundX(P, Alfa);
        P := RotateAroundY(P, Beta);
        if (Phi = 0) or (Backside and (P.Z >= 0)) or
          (not Backside and (P.Z < 0)) then
            FBmp.Canvas.MoveTo(C.X + Round(P.X * R), C.Y + Round(P.Y * R))
        else
        begin
          FBmp.Canvas.Pen.Color := ColorFromZ(P.Z);
          FBmp.Canvas.LineTo(C.X + Round(P.X * R), C.Y + Round(P.Y * R));
        end;
      end;
  end;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, FBmp);
end;

procedure TForm1.GDIMultipleColorsDirect;
var
  Alfa: Double;
  Beta: Double;
  Phi: Integer;
  Lambda: Integer;
  P: TPoint3D;
  Backside: Boolean;

  function ColorFromZ(Z: Single): TColorRef;
  var
    R: Integer;
    G: Integer;
    B: Integer;
  begin
    Z := (Z + 1) / 2;
    R := GetRValue(LineColorFore) - GetRValue(LineColorBack);
    R := GetRValue(LineColorBack) + Round(Z * R);
    G := GetGValue(LineColorFore) - GetGValue(LineColorBack);
    G := GetGValue(LineColorBack) + Round(Z * G);
    B := GetBValue(LineColorFore) - GetBValue(LineColorBack);
    B := GetBValue(LineColorBack) + Round(Z * B);
    Result := RGB(R, G, B);
  end;

begin
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Width := 2;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := BackColor;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.FillRect(PaintBox1.ClientRect);
  Alfa := DegToRad(A);
  Beta := DegToRad(B);
  for Backside := True downto False do
  begin
    if not BackSide then
      PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Width := 3;
    //Latitude
    for Phi := -8 to 8 do
      for Lambda := 0 to 360 do
      begin
        P := Sphere(DegToRad(Phi * 10), DegToRad(Lambda));
        P := RotateAroundX(P, Alfa);
        P := RotateAroundY(P, Beta);
        if (Lambda = 0) or (Backside and (P.Z >= 0)) or
          (not Backside and (P.Z < 0)) then
            PaintBox1.Canvas.MoveTo(C.X + Round(P.X * R), C.Y + Round(P.Y * R))
        else
        begin
          PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Color := ColorFromZ(P.Z);
          PaintBox1.Canvas.LineTo(C.X + Round(P.X * R), C.Y + Round(P.Y * R));
        end;
      end;
    //Longitude
    for Lambda := 0 to 17 do
      for Phi := 0 to 360 do
      begin
        P := Sphere(DegToRad(Phi), DegToRad(Lambda * 10));
        P := RotateAroundX(P, Alfa);
        P := RotateAroundY(P, Beta);
        if (Phi = 0) or (Backside and (P.Z >= 0)) or
          (not Backside and (P.Z < 0)) then
            PaintBox1.Canvas.MoveTo(C.X + Round(P.X * R), C.Y + Round(P.Y * R))
        else
        begin
          PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Color := ColorFromZ(P.Z);
          PaintBox1.Canvas.LineTo(C.X + Round(P.X * R), C.Y + Round(P.Y * R));
        end;
      end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

(With thanks to bummi's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1699210/bummi).)

Comment: Have you tried to animate it (change the angle a tenth of a degree or so 30 times per sec)?

Comment: @NGLN: Well, as the author of [AlgoSim](http://algosim.se), I have seen such animations quite a few times!

Comment: With a script:
https://softwareschule.code.blog/2020/11/18/sphere-script/