# Draw image in 3D space with GDI, GDI+ and Delphi

Tags: delphi, 3d, gdi+, gdi, image-rotation

I need use Delphi XE3 to write a small application to draw on TCanvas an image.
I read this image from DXF file, so I know the filename, the scale about X and Y axies and the 3D space rotation and X, Y and Z axies (for more details about see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521807/dxf-image-entity-group-code-explanation)).

The image is a bitmap so I can use TBitmap to load it.
My problem is: I cannot find the right function to scale on 2 directions and draw "on space" (with rotation).

I need use both GDI and GDI+ if possible.

Comment: So, what projection do you intend to use?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your problem is translating the 3D coordinates to 2D. I think you could do with the following two routines from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15586738/757830):

```
function RotateAroundXAxis(const P: TPoint3D; Alfa: Double): TPoint3D;
begin
  Result.X := P.X;
  Result.Y := P.Y * Cos(Alfa) + P.Z * Sin(Alfa);
  Result.Z := P.Y * -Sin(Alfa) + P.Z * Cos(Alfa);
end;

function RotateAroundYAxis(const P: TPoint3D; Beta: Double): TPoint3D;
begin
  Result.X := P.X * Cos(Beta) + P.Z * Sin(Beta);
  Result.Y := P.Y;
  Result.Z := P.X * -Sin(Beta) + P.Z * Cos(Beta);
end;
```

Actually, that answer deals with more 3D stuff, and handles both GDI and GDI+: it might provide all you need to know.